# How can I create permutation without any library?

Tags: r, permutation

There are n numbers; 1 to n. I want to make permutations of length m with these n numbers. For example, when n is 3 and m is 2, the result will be like this:

```
list(c(1,2), c(1,3), c(2,1), c(2,3), c(3,1), c(3,2))
```

I don't care of the order of the result list.

Comment: Take a look at `combn(3, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be what you want. `a3` is the final output.

```
a1 <- t(combn(3, 2))
a2 <- a1[, c(2, 1)]
a3 <- rbind(a1, a2)
a3
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    2    3
[4,]    2    1
[5,]    3    1
[6,]    3    2
```

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question, is combn() a base function? I don't want to use any package.

Comment: @ohioihoih It is a base R function.